# How to run code even when an exception happens

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, exception, try-catch

I have a code like this:

```
try
{
   do_some_processing();
   // Write Log to appropriate place.
}
catch
{
 // add debug info to log
 // Write Log to appropriate place.
  processException();
}
```

As you can see I need to write log when there is an exception and when there is not.

Is there any way that I can do in one place? and not copy it twice?

as far as I know, finally is called after exception is processed and not before it. Am I right?

Comment: There is no finally in C++.

Comment: Your log for "there is an exception" and "everything's fine" will be different => you don t repeat yourself. (Or I didn t get something)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom

```
class RaiiLogger {
public:
    RaiiLogger() : exception_fired_(true) {}

    void set_success() {
        exception_fired_ = false;
    }

    ~RaiiLogger() {
        if (exception_fired_) {
            // log it
        } else {
            // log it
        }
    }
private:
    bool exception_fired_;
};

void do_work() {
    RaiiLogger logger;
    try {
        // do some work
        logger.set_success();
    } catch(...) {
        // handle exception
    }
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    do_work();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. If there is an exception in do_som_work, logger.set_success is never called and hence no log is written ! Am I wrong?

Comment: @mans You are wrong. Since `logger` is allocated on stack (instead of heap, because no `new` keyword was used) no matter what you do the destructor of `RaiiLogger` class will always be called once the function leaves its scope (even when an exception is thrown). That's the essence of RAII. Note that `set_success` only notifies `logger` that it was successful. **The function does not log anything** - the destructor takes care of it.

Answer (score 3):

Just move it outside of the `try-catch` block:

```
try
{
    do_some_processing();
}
catch
{
    // add debug info to log
    processException();
}

// Write Log to appropriate place.
```

Comment: But if procesException closes application, no log is written! Am I wrong?

Comment: @mans, where is it thrown and why an exception should close the program?

Comment: It is thrown in do_some_processing and it may close application , since ProcessException detected that the problem is not recoverable and needs to close the application. The job of processExepction is to look at the exception and if it is major and it can jot recover, it pass it to a higher level exception processing and that may close the application.

Comment: @mans That's why you should use RAII. Have a look at niktoz's answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
try{
  do_some_processing();
}catch{
  // add debug info to log
  processException();
}

// write log to appropriate place
```